# How not add a same fragment if already has been called before?

Tags: android, fragment

I have 6 buttons and one container. When I pressed a button, and other button, this add in backstack perfectly, but when I pressed a button that I had called before, this add too. So.. if already add back stack, how remove the old fragment when replace with the new fragment? Thanks. It's same logic that Instagram App.

For example:

Fragment A,B,C,D,E,F are my 6 buttons.

Pressed A,B,D,F when pressed back, F,D,B,A... Fine. But... Pressed A,B,C,B,C,B,F and presed back then --> F,B,C,B,C,B,A when should be F,B,C,A directly. Thanks. Sorry for my english.

Comment: I just re-read your question, and I am not sure I understand what you are asking. In your provided example, shouldn't it be F, B, A because there is already an instance of B after A?

Comment: Sorry for my english. Check out how works Instagram. You press the same button more one time and not add to addbackstack. I try to do the same but nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

For `Fragment`s, I do not think there is a built-in mechanism in the back stack that will achieve your requirement.

However, you can keep track of things on your own  and decide which of your Fragments to show when user hits the back key. The idea is to override the `Activity`'s [onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) method and just use [FragmentTransaction.replace](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment%29) without adding anything to the back stack ever.

As a side note, if you can use `Activity` instead of `Fragment`, then you can just use [FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) to launch each `Activity`, and it will behave exactly like you desired.

**Original answer:**

If you look at [addToBackStack (String name)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack%28java.lang.String%29), you can see that you can use a String to distinguish individual `FragmentTransaction`s.

You can then later pass in a String and call [popBackStack (String name, int flags)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) to restore the back stack to your desired state.

Comment: I understand. I have to read that link. Thanks for the suggestion.